# get the band with the maximum value from a xarray stack

Tags: python, geospatial, raster, python-xarray

So, I have 3 rasters stacked in xarray. They represent classes. I want to get which class has the max value in order to assign it a specific class.

Stacked raster:
`stacked_rasters = xr.concat([raster_one, raster_two, raster_three], dim="Classes")`

Now I know how to get the maximum value:
`max_value_raster = stacked_rasters.max(dim="Classes")`

But I really want to get which of the 3 rasters has the maximum value and classify the final raster based on its name. Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?